# El destructor de la clase es llamado despues de instanciar objeto con su constructor de copia

Tags: c++

Me esta pasando que al ejecutar el constructor de copia de la clase String, inmediatamente luego de instanciar mi objeto, se llama al destructor de la clase, y me elimina el objeto recién creado.
Por que sucede esto? Como lo pudo evitar?

```
using namespace std;

class String{

private:
  char *str;

protected:
  char* takeMemory(const char *s);

public:
  String(const char *str = " ");
  ~String(void);
  String(const String &obj);
  friend istream& operator >> (istream &input, String &obj);
  friend ostream& operator << (ostream &input, const String &obj);
};

 #include <iostream>
 #include "StringsClass.h"
 using namespace std;

 int main()
 {
   String str = String();
   String str2;
   cout << "\t\t\t Test Clase string" << endl;
   cout<<str<<endl;
   cin>>str;
   cout<<str<<endl;
   str2 = String(str);
   cout<<str2<<endl;
   return 0;
 }


 String::~String(void){
   delete []str;
   str = NULL;
   cout<<"Destruyendo Objeto str con direccion de memoria "<<this<<endl;
 }

 String::String(const String &obj):str(takeMemory(obj.str)){
   cout<<"Ejecutando constructor de copia"<<endl;
   if(!(this->str) && !obj.str)
       cerr<< "ERROR - Sin memoria"<< endl;
 }

 char* String::takeMemory(const char *s){
   if(s && *s){
    try{
        char *aux = new char[strlen(s) + 1];
        return strcpy(aux,s);
    }catch(std::bad_alloc &){
        //TODO: Tratar exepcion
    }
 }
 return NULL;
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Se está destruyendo un objeto temporal de los que creas. ¿En qué línea detectas que se llama el destructor *inesperadamente*?

Comment: @paperBirdMaster Luego de instanciar mi objeto this->str, apenas sale del constructor de copia va al destructor a eliminar this->str.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
   str2 = String(str);
```

Analicemos esta línea. Lo que sucede aquí es lo siguiente:

- Se crea un objeto temporal que será una copia de `str` (de ahí que se llame al constructor copia).
- Seguidamente se llama al operador de asignación, encargado de copiar la información de dicho objeto temporal a `str2`.
- Finalmente el objeto temporal se destruye ya que la ejecución abandona su ámbito.

Un ejemplo para que se vea un poco más claro:

```
class String{
public:
  String(const char *str = " ")
  { std::cout << "String::String(const char*)\n"; }

  ~String()
  {
    std::cout << "String::~String()\n";
  }

  String(const String &obj)
  {
    std::cout << "String::String(String)\n";
  }

  String& operator=(const String& obj)
  {
    std::cout << "String::operator=(String)\n";
    return *this;
  }

  friend istream& operator >> (istream &input, String &obj);
  friend ostream& operator << (ostream &input, const String &obj);
};

int main()
{
  std::cout << "Creacion objeto str\n";
  String str = String();
  std::cout << "Creacion objeto str2\n";
  String str2(str);
  std::cout << "Creacion objeto str3 (copia temporal)\n";
  String str3;
  str3 = String(str);
  std::cout << "Asignacion str2=str\n";
  str2 = str;
  std::cout << "Liberacion de recursos\n";
  return 0;
}
```

La salida de este ejemplo es la siguiente:

```
Creacion objeto str
    String::String(const char*)
Creacion objeto str2
    String::String(String)
Creacion objeto str3 (copia temporal)
    String::String(const char*)
    String::String(String)
    String::operator=(String)
    String::~String()
Asignacion str2=str
    String::operator=(String)
Liberacion de recursos
    String::~String()
    String::~String()
    String::~String()
```

Que explicado con detalle quedaría así:

```
Creacion objeto str
    String::String(const char*) // 1
Creacion objeto str2
    String::String(String) // 2
Creacion objeto str3 (copia temporal)
    String::String(const char*) // 3
    String::String(String) // 4
    String::operator=(String) // 5
    String::~String() // 6
Asignacion str2=str
    String::operator=(String) // 7
Liberacion de recursos
    String::~String() // 8
    String::~String() // 9
    String::~String() // 10
```

1. Se crea `str`. Se llama a este constructor porque tiene valores porque, pese a tener un argumento, en la declaración se le asigna uno por defecto. Por este motivo sustituye al constructor por defecto
2. Se llama al constructor copia para crear `str2`
3. Se crea el objeto `str3`. Mismo caso que en (1)
4. Se crea el objeto temporal a partir de `str`
5. Se copia el contenido del objeto temporal en `str3`
6. Se destruye el objeto temporal
7. Copia del contenido de `str` en `str2`
8. Destrucción de `str3`
9. Destrucción de `str2`
10. Destrucción de `str`

---

**EDITO**:

¿Por qué en la línea que abre esta respuesta no se llama directamente al constructor copia de `str2`?

El motivo es que, en esa línea, `str2` ya se ha construído y C++ no va a llamar por su propia cuenta al constructor copia (entre otras cosas porque eso podría dar lugar a problemas de estabilidad al dejar recursos sin liberar).

Dicho esto, en C++ hay dos formas de llamar al constructor copia:

```
String str2(str);
String str2 = String(str);
```

Siendo, en este caso, más recomendable la segunda opción ya que la primera se podría llegar a confundir con la declaración de una función. De hecho en C++11 lo correcto sería hacer lo siguiente:

```
String str2{str};
```

Pero ojo, el siguiente código **no** va a llamar al constructor copia que esperamos sino que va a implicar la creación de un objeto temporal:

```
String str2;
str2 = String(str);
```

En este caso lo idóneo sería hacer lo siguiente:

```
String str2;
str2 = str;
```

Ya que así, al menos, nos evitamos una construcción y un borrado.